# Unwanted double(duplicate) saving in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is the problem: I have some database and I am sending from my page some values. They are sent and saved but they are duplicated. I have no cycle or condition for sending it twice. I have one similar code and its working just fine.

```
session_start();

$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastname']);
$town = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['town']);
$street = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['street']);
$housenum = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['housenum']);
$psc = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['psc']);
$tel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tel']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']); 
$payment = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['payment']);

$idBand = "";
$idBand = $_SESSION['idBand'][0];

for($i=1;$i<count($_SESSION['idBand']);$i++)
{
    $idBand = $idBand .", ". $_SESSION['idBand'][$i];
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (idband, payment, firstname, lastname, town, 
                            street, housenum, psc, tel, email)
        VALUES ('$idBand', '$payment', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$town', 
                '$street', '$housenum', '$psc', '$tel', '$email')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
    echo "Objednávka úspěšná.<br>";
    unset($_SESSION['idBand']);
    header("Location:../index.php?index.php=success");
    exit();
} 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        header("Location:../index.php?index.php=ERROR");
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `mysqli_query($conn, $sql)` and `$conn->query($sql)`...???

Comment: You have `mysqli_query($conn,$sql)` and `$conn->query($sql)` in direct succession. That looks like two inserts to me.

Comment: I recommend using prepared statements; not because it will solve your duplicate query call issue, but because it will lessen your code block and should improve security  (from what I've heard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below line from the code because you are already making an entry using `$conn->query($sql)` so just comment that line displayed below.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

and one more thing I have noticed is that `$idBand` taking the first element and then in a loop again it starts from one instead of you can use `join` or `implode` just like below

```
$idBand = implode(",",$_SESSION['idBand']);
```

but this is just another method, not the problem the main problem is triggering query multiple times.

I hope this changes will resolve your issues